# Google Sheets - Adding feet and inches in same column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I want to get the total number of feet and inches from a single column

Right now I currently have my sheet set up like this:

| Length |
| --- |
| 30' 3" |
| 25' 2" |
| 19' 5" |
| 6' 9" |

I'm having trouble finding a formula that would total these numbers. Did I mess up by putting feet and inches in the same column?

I've tried a few formula I found online but they were for excel and didn't seem to work on google sheets. I kept getting a value of 0 or an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=LET(x,SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(SPLIT(A1:A4,"'"""),{1;1/12})),INT(x)&"' "&ROUND(MOD(x,1)*12,2)&"""")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try-

```
=LET(
x,INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A4,"'"""),,1),
y,INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A4,"'"""),,2),
SUM(x)+INT(SUM(y)/12)&"' " & MOD(SUM(y),12) & CHAR(34)
)
```

[image]